# How to change the space between items in ListView UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I tried to change merge value by using ListView.ItemContainerStyle, space between items is decreased, but line seletion is not effect.

[image]

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-25"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

★ How to edit the space and custom line selection like below picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you consider using the [ItemsRepeter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/items-repeater#change-the-layout-of-items) control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ControlTemplate is solved my issue.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource SplitViewCompactPaneThemeLength}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid MinHeight="30" Height="30">
                        My ListView item definition
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't put the spaces inside the data item itself?

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="...your type...">
      <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
           .... your content with bindings
      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Or, you can set `Padding` on your `ItemContainerStyle` instead of `Margin`. Because `Margin` causes spaces **outside** the element, hence these white borders around blue selection, and `Padding` causes spaces between the element's borders and it's content (that is, inside the element).

Comment: Hi Dmitry Arestov,

For your suggestion, The line selection will be bigger, but not have space between items as my expectation picture.